# Bump smooths when joining objects

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, objects, bump

So. As seen in the picture there is a bump node used and the effect disappears after joining the eye to the body. (The eye on the left is joined, the eye on the right is not).

I've tried unwrapping the eye, baking and using an image texture before joining the objects. But as shown in the attached image it bakes black, this is with the diffuse bake type.

It just bakes the same or a different solid colour with different bake types. So I'm confused as to why this is all happening. Any ideas? Am I going wrong somewhere?

Thanks in advance for anyone who answers :)[image: Eye (one joined and one not joined to show what happens when joining. UV map and Node setup]

Answer (score 0):

Before joining them, Do both objects have different UVMap? If it is then add a `UVMap` node and select the old UVMap they have.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, where does the UV Map node need to plug into? I've not used it before. I tried plugging it into the Material Outputs displacement input, but got the same result. Correct UV map selected.